# Incorrect syntax near ','. exec sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_bandejaPedidos]
    @id_usuario INT = 0,
    @selector NVARCHAR(50) = '',
    @order NVARCHAR(50) = '',
    @consulta NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF(@selector = '' AND @order = '')
            SET @selector = 'pedi.fecha_creacion';
            SET @order = 'DESC';

    SET @consulta = 'pedi.id,pedi.folio,pedi.cliente_id,
                     eniac_clientes.rfc,
                     eniac_clientes.nombre+\" \"+eniac_clientes.apellido_paterno+\" \"+eniac_clientes.apellido_paterno AS Cliente,
                     pedi.fecha_creacion,
                     pedi.importe,
                     estatus_pi.estatus,
                     eniac_sucursales.nombre AS sucursal

                     FROM pedidos AS pedi

    INNER JOIN gestion_pedidos_eniac.dbo.sucursales AS eniac_sucursales ON eniac_sucursales.id_sucursal = pedi.sucursal_id
    INNER JOIN gestion_pedidos_eniac.dbo.clientes AS eniac_clientes ON eniac_clientes.id = pedi.cliente_id
    INNER JOIN estatus_pedido AS estatus_pi ON estatus_pi.id = pedi.estatus

    WHERE pedi.usuario_id = '+ CAST(@id_usuario AS NVARCHAR)+'
    ORDER BY ' + @selector + ' '+ @order + ''

    EXEC sp_executesql @consulta

END
```

Error is:

> Incorrect syntax near ','

and I do not understand that if the entire query is fine without zero errors.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

1. You have missed `select`
2. Use `''''` instead of `\" \"`
3. Debug Query Using Printing its output

   ```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_bandejaPedidos]

       @id_usuario INT = 0,
       @selector NVARCHAR(50) = '',
       @order NVARCHAR(50) = '',
       @consulta NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
   AS

   BEGIN

       SET NOCOUNT ON;
       IF(@selector = '' AND @order = '')
               SET @selector = 'pedi.fecha_creacion';
               SET @order = 'DESC';

       SET @consulta = 'select pedi.id,pedi.folio,pedi.cliente_id,
                        eniac_clientes.rfc,
                        eniac_clientes.nombre+'' ''+eniac_clientes.apellido_paterno+'' ''+eniac_clientes.apellido_paterno AS Cliente,
                        pedi.fecha_creacion,
                        pedi.importe,
                        estatus_pi.estatus,
                        eniac_sucursales.nombre AS sucursal

                        FROM pedidos AS pedi

       INNER JOIN gestion_pedidos_eniac.dbo.sucursales AS eniac_sucursales ON eniac_sucursales.id_sucursal = pedi.sucursal_id
       INNER JOIN gestion_pedidos_eniac.dbo.clientes AS eniac_clientes ON eniac_clientes.id = pedi.cliente_id
       INNER JOIN estatus_pedido AS estatus_pi ON estatus_pi.id = pedi.estatus

       WHERE pedi.usuario_id = '+ CAST(@id_usuario AS NVARCHAR)+'
       ORDER BY ' + @selector + ' '+ @order + ''

       EXEC sp_executesql @consulta


     print (@consulta) END
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`SET @consulta = 'pedi.id,pedi.folio,pedi.cliente_id,`
should be
`SET @consulta = 'SELECT pedi.id,pedi.folio,pedi.cliente_id,`

Answer (score 1):

You have missed `select` in your statement.

It should be `SET @consulta = 'select pedi.id,pedi.folio,pedi.cliente_id,` and so on

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues in your code.

- Add `SELECT` to the start of your code:
  `'SELECT pedi.id,pedi.folio, ...`
- Add `BEGIN/END` to the `IF` clause, as right now the second line runs always:
  IF(@selector = '' AND @order = '')
          SET @selector = 'pedi.fecha_creacion';
          SET @order = 'DESC';
- You doesn't filter your input and the SQL Injection can occur
- Use `''` instead of `\"`